# Insert (not overwrite) to file in C

Tags: c, file

In C, I'm using `fseek` to go back to a position in the file. When I then write to the file with `fprintf`, it overwrites the characters at that location. Is there a way to make fprintf/another function insert, instead of overwrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "no".  If you need to insert, you really need to rewrite the entire file after the insertion.

Comment: +1. ...or use some sort of indexing scheme where you write data, e.g., after the existing data, and the index tells how to arrange it in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

No. C has no concept of "file insertion". You'll have to manually create a 'gap' in the file by copying all the data that comes AFTER your insertion point to a spot farther down the file.